# If two functions are one-to-one, will the sum of it also be one-to-one?

Tags: functions

If $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ are both one-to-one functions, is $f + g$ also one-to-one? How do I show it whether $f+g$ is one-to-one or not?

Comment: Try to find an example where $f+g=0$.

Comment: not in genral, for example, $f(x)=x,g(x)=-x$ are 1-1 but $f(x)+g(x)=0$ isn't 1-1.

Comment: Although, if both functions are strictly increasing or both strictly decreasing then yes.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample suffices. Take $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)= x$ and $g(x)=-x$ (as mentioned in the comments).

Clearly, $f(x) + g(x) = 0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f+g$ is not one-one.

However, if $f, g$ are both strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, then the statement holds. WLOG consider the case where $f,g$ are differentiable and such that $f'(x)>0$ and $g'(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Obviously, $(f+g)'(x) = f'(x) + g'(x) > 0$.

Comment: Arh I know about it. Means that if we assume that any values for f(x) and g(x) that gives the result of f(x)+g(x)=0, then f+g is not one-to-one right?